# Mp3 file uploaded to Ghpages won't play. I have tried using rawgit to host the file and githubusercontent and it still won't work?

Tags: html, github, html5-audio, github-pages

This is the local code that I have and it works.

```
  <audio preload="auto" autoplay="autoplay">
    <source src="halloween_theme.mp3" type="audio/mp3" />
  </audio>
```

This was what I read to do from another stackoverflow

```
  <audio preload="auto" autoplay="autoplay">
    <source src="https://raw.githubusercontent.com/jerryhoglen/halloween_site/master/halloween_theme.mp3" type="audio/mp3" />
  </audio>
```

I have tried hosting the track on google drive and it won't work there either.

Comment: the src `https://raw.githubusercontent.com/jerryhoglen/halloween_site/master/halloween_theme.mp3` is going to page not found. Double check the URL

Comment: Are you sure that your file upload to GitHub was successful, because you are not allowed to git more than 100mb and upload more than 25mb (via [GitHub's website](https://www.github.com)) to GitHub.

Answer (score 0):

I found the answer. Chrome has updated and removed the autoplay feature but there is a workaround using iframes to play mp3 audio.

```
  <iframe src="audio/halloween_theme.mp3" allow="autoplay" style="display:none" id="iframeAudio"></iframe>
```